# TypeError('Keyword argument not understood:', kwarg) TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'inputs')

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pooling

The following code is for fake news detection with a dEFEND model using Tensorflow and Keras. For some reason, I keep getting an error. This is a TypeError with parameter 'inputs'. I don't understand why this error is being raised. Here is my code:

```
import keras
import pickle
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import *
from keras.layers import *
from keras import optimizers
from keras.optimizers import *
from keras.callbacks import *
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras import backend as K
from keras.utils.generic_utils import CustomObjectScope
from keras.layers import Layer
from keras import initializers
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score, precision_score, recall_score, accuracy_score, roc_auc_score
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model

from tqdm import tqdm

import re
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
import jsonlines

def load_glove_embedding(path, dim, word_index):
    embeddings_index = {}
    f = open(path)

    print('Generating GloVe embedding...')
    for line in tqdm(f):
        values = line.split()
        word = values[0]
        coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
        embeddings_index[word] = coefs
    f.close()

    embedding_matrix = np.zeros((len(word_index) + 1, dim))

    for word, i in word_index.items():
        embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
        if embedding_vector is not None:
            # words not found in embedding index will be all-zeros.
            embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
    print('Loaded GloVe embedding')

    return embedding_matrix

def load_glove_embedding(path, dim, word_index):
    embeddings_index = {}
    f = open(path)

    print('Generating GloVe embedding...')
    for line in tqdm(f):
        values = line.split()
        word = values[0]
        coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
        embeddings_index[word] = coefs
    f.close()

    embedding_matrix = np.zeros((len(word_index) + 1, dim))

    for word, i in word_index.items():
        embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
        if embedding_vector is not None:
            # words not found in embedding index will be all-zeros.
            embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
    print('Loaded GloVe embedding')

    return embedding_matrix

class AttLayer(Layer):
    """
    Attention layer used for the calcualting attention in word and sentence levels
    """

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AttLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.init = initializers.get('normal')
        self.supports_masking = True
        self.attention_dim = 100

    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert len(input_shape) == 3
        self.W = K.variable(self.init((input_shape[-1], self.attention_dim)))
        self.b = K.variable(self.init((self.attention_dim,)))
        self.u = K.variable(self.init((self.attention_dim, 1)))
        self._trainable_weights = [self.W, self.b, self.u]
        super(AttLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def compute_mask(self, inputs, mask=None):
        return mask

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        # size of x :[batch_size, sel_len, attention_dim]
        # size of u :[batch_size, attention_dim]
        # uit = tanh(xW+b)
        uit = K.tanh(K.bias_add(K.dot(x, self.W), self.b))
        ait = K.dot(uit, self.u)
        ait = K.squeeze(ait, -1)
        ait = K.exp(ait)
        if mask is not None:
            # Cast the mask to floatX to avoid float64 upcasting in theano
            ait *= K.cast(mask, K.floatx())
        print(ait)
        ait /= K.cast(K.sum(ait, axis=1, keepdims=True) + K.epsilon(), K.floatx())
        ait = K.expand_dims(ait)
        weighted_input = x * ait
        output = K.sum(weighted_input, axis=1)

        return output

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], input_shape[-1])

TOKENIZER_STATE_PATH = './saved_models/tokenizer.p'
GLOVE_EMBEDDING_PATH = './saved_models/zhs_wiki_glove.vectors.100d.txt'

class Metrics(Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        self.log_file = open('./data/Log_Defend_Weibo_content.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8')

    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.val_f1s = []
        self.val_recalls = []
        self.val_precisions = []
        self.val_auc = []
        self.val_acc = []

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        val_predict_onehot = (
            np.asarray(self.model.predict([self.validation_data[0], self.validation_data[1]]))).round()
        val_targ_onehot = self.validation_data[2]
        val_predict = np.argmax(val_predict_onehot, axis=1)
        val_targ = np.argmax(val_targ_onehot, axis=1)
        _val_f1 = f1_score(val_targ, val_predict)
        _val_recall = recall_score(val_targ, val_predict)
        _val_precision = precision_score(val_targ, val_predict)
        _val_auc = roc_auc_score(val_targ, val_predict)
        _val_acc = accuracy_score(val_targ, val_predict)
        self.val_f1s.append(_val_f1)
        self.val_recalls.append(_val_recall)
        self.val_precisions.append(_val_precision)
        self.val_auc.append(_val_auc)
        self.val_acc.append(_val_acc)
        print("Epoch: %d - val_accuracy: % f - val_precision: % f - val_recall % f val_f1: %f auc: %f" % (
            epoch, _val_acc, _val_precision, _val_recall, _val_f1, _val_auc))
        self.log_file.write(
            "Epoch: %d - val_accuracy: % f - val_precision: % f - val_recall % f val_f1: %f auc: %f\n" % (epoch,
                                                                    _val_acc,
                                                                    _val_precision,
                                                                    _val_recall,
                                                                    _val_f1,
                                                                    _val_auc))
        return

class Defend():
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = None
        self.MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH = 120
        self.MAX_SENTENCE_COUNT = 50
        self.MAX_COMS_COUNT = 150
        self.MAX_COMS_LENGTH = 120
        self.VOCABULARY_SIZE = 0
        self.word_embedding = None
        self.model = None
        self.word_attention_model = None
        self.sentence_comment_co_model = None
        self.tokenizer = None
        self.class_count = 2
        self.metrics = Metrics()

        # Variables for calculating attention weights
        self.news_content_word_level_encoder = None
        self.comment_word_level_encoder = None
        self.news_content_sentence_level_encoder = None
        self.comment_sequence_encoder = None
        self.co_attention_model = None

    def _generate_embedding(self, path, dim):
        return load_glove_embedding(path, dim, self.tokenizer.word_index)

    def _build_model(self, n_classes=2, embedding_dim=100, embeddings_path=False, aff_dim=80):
        GLOVE_DIR = "."
        embeddings_index = {}
        f = open('./saved_models/zhs_wiki_glove.vectors.100d.txt', encoding='utf-8')
        for line in f:
            values = line.split()
            word = values[0]
            coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
            embeddings_index[word] = coefs
        f.close()
        word_index = self.tokenizer.word_index
        embedding_matrix = np.random.random((len(word_index) + 1, embedding_dim))
        for word, i in word_index.items():
            embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
            if embedding_vector is not None:
                embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector

        embedding_layer = Embedding(len(word_index) + 1,
                       embedding_dim,
                       weights=[embedding_matrix],
                       input_length=self.MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH,
                       trainable=True,
                       mask_zero=True)

        com_embedding_layer = Embedding(len(word_index) + 1,
                         embedding_dim,
                         weights=[embedding_matrix],
                         input_length=self.MAX_COMS_LENGTH,
                         trainable=True,
                         mask_zero=True)

        sentence_input = Input(shape=(self.MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
        embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sentence_input)
        embedded_sequences = Lambda(lambda x: x, output_shape=lambda s: s)(embedded_sequences)
        l_lstm = Bidirectional(GRU(100, return_sequences=True), name='word_lstm')(Reshape((120, 100))(embedded_sequences))
        l_att = AttLayer(name='word_attention')(l_lstm)
        sentEncoder = Model(sentence_input, l_att)
        plot_model(sentEncoder, to_file='SentenceEncoder.png', show_shapes=True)

        self.news_content_word_level_encoder = sentEncoder

        content_input = Input(shape=(self.MAX_SENTENCE_COUNT, self.MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH), dtype='int32')
        content_encoder = TimeDistributed(sentEncoder)(content_input)
        l_lstm_sent = Bidirectional(GRU(100, return_sequences=True), name='sentence_lstm')(content_encoder)

        self.news_content_sentence_level_encoder = Model(content_input, l_lstm_sent)

        content_input_ = Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(x, axis=3))(l_lstm_sent)  # for channels
        pooling_layer = keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(inputs=content_input_, pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='valid', data_format='channels_last',name='average_pooling_content')
        preds = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(pooling_layer)
        model = Model(inputs=content_input_, outputs=preds)
        model.summary()
        plot_model(model, to_file='CHATT_content.png', show_shapes=True)

        optimize = optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001)
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                      optimizer=optimize,
                      metrics=['accuracy'])

        return model
    def train(self, train_x, train_y, val_x, val_y,
              batch_size=20, epochs=10,
              embeddings_path=False,
              saved_model_dir='saved_models', saved_model_filename=None, ):
        # Fit the vocabulary set on the content and comments
        self._fit_on_texts_and_comments(train_x, val_x)
        self.model = self._build_model(
            n_classes=train_y.shape[-1],
            embedding_dim=100,
            embeddings_path=embeddings_path)

        # Create encoded input for content and comments
        encoded_train_x = self._encode_texts(train_x)
        encoded_val_x = self._encode_texts(val_x)
        """encoded_train_c = self._encode_comments(train_c)
        encoded_val_c = self._encode_comments(val_c)"""
        callbacks = []
        callbacks.append(LambdaCallback(
                on_epoch_end=lambda epoch, logs: self._save_tokenizer_on_epoch_end(
                    os.path.join(saved_model_dir, self._get_tokenizer_filename(saved_model_filename)), epoch))
        )

        if saved_model_filename:
            callbacks.append(
                ModelCheckpoint(
                    filepath=os.path.join(saved_model_dir, saved_model_filename),
                    monitor='val_loss',
                    save_best_only=True,
                    save_weights_only=False,
                )
            )
        callbacks.append(self.metrics)
        early_stopping = EarlyStopping(
                      monitor='val_acc',
                      min_delta=0.0005,
                      patience=5,
                      verbose=1,
                      restore_best_weights=True,
                  )
        lr_scheduler = ReduceLROnPlateau(
                      monitor='val_acc',
                      factor=0.5,
                      patience=3,
                      min_lr=0.00002,
                      verbose=1,
                  )
        callbacks.append(early_stopping)
        callbacks.append(lr_scheduler)
        print(type(callbacks))
        self.model.fit(encoded_train_x, y=train_y,
                       validation_data=(encoded_val_x, val_y),
                       batch_size=batch_size,
                       epochs=epochs,
                       verbose=1,
                       callbacks=callbacks)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # dataset used for training
    VALIDATION_SPLIT = 0.25
    contents = []
    #comments = []
    labels = []
    #texts = []
    ids = []

    with open('./data/fake_release_all.json', 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
        for item in jsonlines.Reader(json_file):
            sentences = sent_tokenize(item['content'])
            j = 0
            k = 0
            for sentence in sentences:
                #print(sentence)
                sentence = clean_str(sentence)
                k+=len(sentence)
                #print(sentence)
                sentences[j] = sentence
                j += 1
            #print(sentences)
            if k>=100:
                contents.append(sentences)
                ids.append(item['id'])
                labels.append(item['label'])
            else:
              continue
    with open('./data/real_release_all.json', 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
        for item in jsonlines.Reader(json_file):
            sentences = sent_tokenize(item['content'])
            j = 0
            k = 0
            for sentence in sentences:
                sentence = clean_str(sentence)
                k+=len(sentence)
                sentences[j] = sentence
                j += 1
            if k>=100:
                contents.append(sentences)
                ids.append(item['id'])
                labels.append(item['label'])
            else:
              continue

    labels = np.asarray(labels)
    labels = to_categorical(labels)

    content_ids = set(ids)

    id_train, id_test, x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val= train_test_split(ids,contents, labels,
                                                  test_size=VALIDATION_SPLIT, random_state=42,
                                                  stratify=labels)

    # Train and save the model
    SAVED_MODEL_FILENAME = 'Defend_Weibo_model_content.h5'
    h = Defend()
    h.train(x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val,
            batch_size=20,
            epochs=30,
            embeddings_path='./zhs_wiki_glove.vectors.100d.txt',
            saved_model_dir=SAVED_MODEL_DIR,
            saved_model_filename=SAVED_MODEL_FILENAME)
```

And here is the error:

```
    Tensor("word_attention/Exp:0", shape=(?, 120), dtype=float32)
    Tensor("time_distributed_1/word_attention/Exp:0", shape=(?, ?), dtype=float32)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File"C:/Users/hqint/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/7460/dEFEND/fake_news_detection/dEFEND/defend_content.py", line 684, in <module>saved_model_filename=SAVED_MODEL_FILENAME)

File "C:/Users/hqint/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/7460/dEFEND/fake_news_detection/dEFEND/defend_content.py", line 380, in train embeddings_path=embeddings_path)

File "C:/Users/hqint/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/7460/dEFEND/fake_news_detection/dEFEND/defend_content.py", line 271, in _build_model
        pooling_layer = keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(inputs=content_input_, pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='valid', data_format='channels_last',name='average_pooling_content')

File "C:\Users\hqint\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\hqint\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\pooling.py", line 317, in __init__
        data_format, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\hqint\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\pooling.py", line 171, in __init__
        super(_Pooling2D, self).__init__(**kwargs)

File "C:\Users\hqint\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 128, in __init__
   raise TypeError('Keyword argument not understood:', kwarg)

TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'inputs')
```

How can I fix this TypeError? I have installed TensorFlow 1.13.1 and Keras 2.2.4. It seems that the input tensor of the `average_pooling` layer is the error, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Are you sure you are using that AveragePooling2D correctly? The docs don't mention any "inputs" kwarg. https://keras.io/api/layers/pooling_layers/average_pooling2d/
In the example they add the data by calling the resulting object as a function with the dataset.

Comment: You should try `keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(...)(content_input_)` instead of `keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(inputs=content_input_,..)`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Keras is trying to pass a keyword argument named inputs to a function, but the function does not accept that keyword argument. In `Keras 2.4.0` and later, the inputs keyword argument was removed from the Model class. If you are using an older version of Keras, you will need to update your code to use the new inputs argument instead. You can remove the `output=` and `input =` keywords which has solved the issue for others as seen in this similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60690327/typeerror-keyword-argument-not-understood-inputs)